# how to make a variable change value within an if statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, variables, return-value

I have a dataframe g with stock data with dates and price numbers. When I want Date1 to exist, Within the if statement, g doesn't become the dates specified. Here is the basic code:

```
Date1 <- "2020-10-31"
Date2 <- "2020-11-09"

if (exists(Date1)) {
  g <- window(g,start=Date1,end=Date2)
}

g
```

I don't want to attach dput, but I do want to know how to get g to equal something else in an if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, I understand your problem. But does this already solve it?

```
Date1 <- "2020-10-31"
Date2 <- "2020-11-09"

if (exists('Date1')) {
  g <- window(g,start=Date1,end=Date2)
}

g
```

Comment: No, the g variable doesn't change value. I get an error too: `Error in exists(Date1) : invalid first argument`

Comment: I didn't see the quotation marks with exist`'Date1'` in `exists('Date1')`. Thanks, this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The question's poorly formulated, but I think you want `ifelse`

e.g.:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

tibble(date = as_date(c("2020-10-31", "2020-11-09"))) %>%
  mutate(tag = ifelse(date == as_date("2020-10-31"), 'Date1', 'other date'))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  date       tag       
  <date>     <chr>     
1 2020-10-31 Date1     
2 2020-11-09 other date
```